# PHP unable to send/receive sockets to a remote connection

Tags: php, linux, sockets, centos, redhat

I'm trying to use a script to ping a remote Minecraft server and decrypt the information to be displayed on a web page. The script I am using can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/FunnyItsElmo/PHP-Minecraft-Server-Status-Query/blob/master/MinecraftServerStatus/status.class.php).

When we tested this on an Ubuntu 15.04 machine, it worked as expected. However, when we put it on a Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.1 machine, the script was no longer able to make a connection to the page - I was unable to determine where or what was going wrong.

The PHP packages I have installed on the machine are as follows:

```
php.x86_64                         5.4.16-36.el7_1         @rhel-x86_64-server-7
php-cli.x86_64                     5.4.16-36.el7_1         @rhel-x86_64-server-7
php-common.x86_64                  5.4.16-36.el7_1         @rhel-x86_64-server-7
php-gd.x86_64                      5.4.16-36.el7_1         @rhel-x86_64-server-7
php-mbstring.x86_64                5.4.16-36.el7_1         @rhel-x86_64-server-optional-7
php-mysql.x86_64                   5.4.16-36.el7_1         @rhel-x86_64-server-7
php-pdo.x86_64                     5.4.16-36.el7_1         @rhel-x86_64-server-7
php-xml.x86_64                     5.4.16-36.el7_1         @rhel-x86_64-server-7
```

The website I am testing this on can be found [here](http://rit.j-f.co/) and more detailed information about the PHP setup on the machine can also be found [here](http://rit.j-f.co/test.php).

Is there something that I'm missing for as to why this script isn't able to make the connection? I had considered a firewall, but even when I had the script query localhost (webpage and Minecraft server are on the same machine), it was still unable to make the connection.

Comment: Any error ? You can try to echo `socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket))`.

Comment: @frz3993 I added that line to the script on the web page. Seems like all I get is "`Success`". You can see it on the website linked above as well. Any further thoughts?

Comment: `var_dump` the result, check apache error_log ?

Comment: @frz3993 Could you provide a context of how to use it in this situation? I'm not much of a PHP programmer, and I tried reading the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) but I can't figure how to apply that to this case.